# Only fetch a subset of remote git branches or only display a subset of them in gitk

Tags: git

If other developers push their local branches to a shared remote repository before committing to trunk (to share, backup, or centrally store them for access from multiple machines), is there a way for me to easily only fetch my own branches or selectively delete local references to others' remote branches? If not, is there a way to only show a subset of remote branches in gitk, so I can see where my branches are relative to my remote branches, but not have the graph cluttered by everyone else's remote branches?

Comment: I hope it's OK that I made a slight edit to your title, since a "remote" in git is a distinct concept from a branch in a remote - your question is about the latter, and the title was a bit misleading.

Comment: Talking about 'trunk' in Git context is a bit weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way of only fetching particular branches from a remote:

The refs (including branches) that are fetched from a remote are controlled with the config option `remote.<remote-name>.fetch`.  For example, your `remote.origin.fetch` is probably the refspec:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

... which means to make fetch the names of all the refs under `refs/heads/` in the remote repository, and make them available under `refs/remotes/origin/` in your local repository.  (The `+` means to do forced updates, so your remote-tracking branches can be updated even if the update wouldn't be a fast-forward.)

You can instead list multiple refspecs that specify particular branches to fetch, e.g. changing this with:

```
 git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
 git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/blah:refs/remotes/origin/blah
```

... and then the next time only `master` and `blah` will be fetched.

Of course, you already locally have lots of remote-tracking branches, and `gitk` will still show those.  You can remove each of the ones you're not interested in with:

```
git branch -r -d origin/uninteresting
```

Comment: Instead of deleting each remote tracking branch separately, you should be able to do `git remote prune origin`, which I think will take fetchspecs into consideration

Comment: @knittl: The documentation doesn't suggest that, and I've just tested that in git 1.7.0.4, with `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` and it doesn't seem to remove them...

Comment: ok, wrong assumption from my side :) would be interesting if that is considered expected behavior

Comment: Works great, thanks! To clarify, there is no built in way to prune my own old branches in the remote other than separate calls of the following form: `git push origin :mybranches/branchA` (excluding using shell functionality, such as `git push origin :mybranches/{branchA,branchB}`), is that correct?

Comment: @jonderry: you can do them all in one command line, if you like, such as: `git push origin :experiment1 :experiment2` - I don't think it can get simpler than that, since it can't automatically know which branches you want to delete.