# How to git fetch and prune only a subset of exactly specified refs

Tags: git, git-fetch

I want to synchronize **certain subset** of custom refs from origin to the local copy:

```
git fetch --force --prune origin refs/x/1:refs/x/1 refs/x/3:refs/x/3
```

I need `git fetch` to delete local ref when the remote one is missing. However, `git fetch` fails when any ref is missing on the remote: `fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/x/...` and the existing refs are not fetched.

*Workarounds*

1. Fetch ref one by one, delete local ref on error. But it's slow for many refs.
2. Append `*` to refs and use `--prune` param:

   ```
   git fetch --force --prune origin refs/x/1*:refs/x/1* refs/x/3*:refs/x/3*
   ```

   Drawback is, that it may fetch unnecessary refs, too (like `refs/x/11` etc.)

Is there any better way how to make git fetch synchronize subset of remote refs?

Comment: I think a possible restatement of this question is "How to fetch and prune only a subset of refs?" (If yes I think this is a clearer question. I didn't realize you didn't wish to fetch everything until the second to last sentence...)

Comment: @TTT I've tried to reword that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Good edit. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7563671/184546), though as written yours is more general, so I don't think I would call this a dup. The comments in the answer include your pruning question, with no simple solution offered, though that was 12 years ago...